# Subject verb for causes/cause

Tags: verb-agreement, subjects

Kindly let me know which one is correct and why ?

A diet high in oil cause*s* more obesity than diet high in sugar.
**OR**
A diet high in oil cause more obesity than diet high in sugar.

Answer (score 1):

Correct: 'A diet high in oil causes more obesity than diet high in sugar.' because the subject is, 'a high diet', so you would conjugate the verb, 'to cause', as you would for he, she, or it.